# MVC - Adding new records that were created on the client

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I'm having problems with my MVC web application adding new records that have been created on the client side. When I click the submit submit button the viewmodel that is passed to the controller only contains the records that were there already and not the new ones that were added by javascript.
This is a simplified version of the code that I'm using:-

**Server code**

```
public class person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
}

public class viewmodel
{
    List<person> people { get; set; }
}
```

**The View**

```
<div id="dv_people">

  @{

     for (c = 0; c < Model.people.Count(); c++)
     {

       @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.people[c].firstname);
       @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.people[c].lastname);
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.people[c].ID);

     }
  }

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function addPerson(firsname, lastname, uniqueIndex){
    var htm = '<input class="text-box single-line" id="people_' + uniqueIndex + '__firstname" name="people[' + uniqueIndex + '].firstname" type="text" value="' + firsname + '">'
    htm = htm + '<input class="text-box single-line" id="people_' + uniqueIndex + '__lastname" name="people[' + uniqueIndex + '].lastname" type="text" value="' + lastname + '">'
    htm = htm + '<input id="people_' + uniqueIndex + '__ID" name="people[' + uniqueIndex + '].ID" type="hidden" value="' + uniqueIndex + '">'

    $("#dv_poeple").append(htm)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically Add Fields to Razor Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822699/dynamically-add-fields-to-razor-form)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I want to be able to post the form back to the controller with the new data binded to the view model